# Basic authentication feature in azure application gateway required

Tags: azure, basic-authentication, azure-application-gateway

I have an application in azure cloud with active and passive mode that automatically switches when one is down, another becomes active. Now I am trying to implement azure application gateway, in front of the application for High Availability and failover check that does the health check probe and upon returning 200 response code it is able to identify the active node and routes the request to healthy node as expected , However when the application is using Basic Auth, then it throws 401 error, I  want to find a way to fix this within application gateway.I don't want to use any proxy services like Nginx or Haproxy to achieve this. Any help or suggestions is appreciated ?

Comment: Please provide more information. Show us your code, what you already tried and give try to properly format your question for better readability. More information about a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Comment: Mutual auth is not supported in Azure layer 7 load balancer. Even the basic authentication for probe URL's is not yet supported in Azure Load balancer

Answer (score 0):

I assume it throws 401 until you authenticate again.

What it probably happens is that the browser is getting a token to authenticate to App1, and then you are trying to use that token to authenticate to App2.

Even when both App Services has the same code, for AAD those might be different applications.

To fix that, you need to make sure you are using the same Service Principal. When you setup easy auth, go to the Advanced tab and make sure that both app services has the exact same values everywhere:

[image]